# Javascript: Basic for loop is not working

Tags: javascript, for-loop, referenceerror

Is there any reason why the following would not work:

```
for (i=0;i < someArray.length;i++) {
    if (someArray[i].indexOf("something") !== -1) {
        //do something here
    }
}
```

The most basic "for" loop possible. But it doesn't work. On the first line (declaration of the loop, not inside the loop), I get "Uncaught reference error; i is not defined."

I have this page open in one Chrome tab, and another earlier version of the page open in another tab. In the other tab, this loop works just fine; in the first tab, this code throws an error.

**EDIT - July 2 2015**

The response about strict mode was helpful. After reading up a bit and going through the code I've got a handle on what's going on.

The confusing bit was that both versions of the code look like this, with some minor differences (requirejs module):

```
define(
    'viewModels/someViewModel',
    ['dependency1', 'dependency2', 'dependency3'],
    function(dep1, dep2, dep3) {

        "use strict";

        function SomeViewModel(arg1, arg2) {
            var self = this;
            self.initialize();

            self.removeRefinement = function(refinementString) {
                var refinementArray = refinementString.split("&");

                for (i=0;i < navigationArray.length;i++) { //<-- error

                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

One version throws the reference error. One doesn't.

This is a large web application with many other pages and Javascript files. The only thing I could think of was that in one version of the code, maybe i had been inadvertently globally defined somewhere else in the app, where strict mode wasn't enabled. After running to the breakpoint and checking "window" I see that's exactly what's happening.

Thanks =D

Comment: Wait, why can't you change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), you'll get the error `Uncaught reference error; i is not defined.` If you're not in strict mode, you won't get the error.

This will throw the error

```js
'use strict'
var someArray = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'];

for (i=0;i < someArray.length;i++) {
  console.log(i)
  if (someArray[i].indexOf("something") !== -1) {
    //do something here
  }
}
```

This won't

```js
var someArray = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'];

for (i=0;i < someArray.length;i++) {
  console.log(i)
  if (someArray[i].indexOf("something") !== -1) {
    //do something here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when you declare a variable it must be declared like this `var i = 0;`

a for loop looks like this:

**JavaScript**

```
for(var i = 0; i == 10; i++)
{

}
```

Comment: Not the correct answer. If you read the question carefully, the user explains that he cannot add the `var` declaration. Also, the answer is not complete and is only valid in strict mode.

Comment: Whoops, yeah. I noticed it after I submitted the answer hence why I commented to the users post.

Comment: Your first statement is false, global variables can be declared without `var`.